# Natural Deduction: An unusual presentation?

Tags: logic, reference-request, proof-theory, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

**1. Context**
On page 241 of their paper [*Natural deduction and coherence for weakly distributive categories*](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/nets/nets.pdf) Blute et al give the right- and left-introduction rules of multiplicative conjunction for (multiplicative) linear logic as follows:

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{{\Gamma_1\vdash \Gamma_2,A,\Gamma_3}\qquad{\Delta_1\vdash \Delta_2,B,\Delta_3}}{\Gamma_1, \Delta_1 \vdash \Gamma_2, \Delta_2, A \otimes B, \Gamma_3, \Delta_3}(\otimes R)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{{\Gamma_1,A,B,\Gamma_2\vdash \Gamma_3}}{\Gamma_1,A \otimes B, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Gamma_3}(\otimes L)
\end{equation}

They then write:

> Thinking in terms of natural deduction, these rules induct a (bijective, once we have the right equations) correspondence indicated by these “rules”:
> \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{{\Gamma_1,A \otimes B, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta}}{\Gamma_1,A,B,\Gamma_2\vdash \Delta}(\otimes -intro),
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{{\Gamma_1,A, B, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta}}{\Gamma_1, A \otimes B,\Gamma_2\vdash \Delta}(\otimes -elim)
> \end{equation}

**2. Question**
I am familiar with the Fitch notation for natural deduction as well as the presentation given in Girard's *Proofs and Types*. However, the sequent-like (?) notation used here eludes me.

- How is it read? How does one translate this presentation into the one given by Girard say?
- Are there any texts that introduce/explain this notation?

EDIT:
In the comments it was suggested that this is a typo and that the (-elim) and (-intro) names should be swapped. However, the authors repeat the "typo" on the same page leaving me to believe that they read the inference rules of natural deduction bottom-up:

> A curiosity is the apparent lack of symmetry between unit introduction and elimination links. Logically they correspond to the (again bijective) correspondence:
> \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{{\Gamma_1, \top, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta}}{\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2\vdash \Delta}(\top -intro),
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{{\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta}}{\Gamma_1,\top, \Gamma_2\vdash \Delta}(\top -elim)
> \end{equation}

Comment: Maybe the -intro and -elim names must be swapped.. .

Comment: I think it's a typo - the elimination and introduction terms should be swapped.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Ah okay, but then one should swap the two expressions rather than the -intro and -elim names, right? That way it becomes clear that ($\otimes$ R) translates to ($\otimes$ -intro) and  ($\otimes$ L) translates to ($\otimes$ -elim).

Comment: Besides, the authors seem to repeat the "typo" further down in the text (see my edit). This leaves me to believe that this isn't a typo but that they read the inference rules bottom-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Long comment*

Based on the previous **Def.1.1** the tensor $⊗$ "works like" AND: $A ⊗ \top \to A$, and thus the pair of rules above are exactly those for $∧$ in Sequent Calculus.

The first one reads (simplifying contexts) "from premises 'if $C$ then $A$' and 'if $C$ then $B$', the conclusion 'if $C$ then $A⊗B$' follows".

And the second one reads: "from premises 'if $A$ then $C$' and 'if $B$ then $C$', the conclusion 'if $A⊗B$' then $C$' follows".

Now about the main issue: *the text of the paper is right*. The "standard" translation from SC to ND maps e.g. $(\text L \land)$ to $(\land \text E)$ and so on (see Negri & von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Structural_Proof_Theory/ZvACGkn9138C), page 173).

Why so? *You are right*: the "mapping" works bottom-up:

> $(\text L \land) \text { rule } \dfrac {A,B \vdash C}{A \land B \vdash C} \text { will be } (\land \text E) \text { rule } \dfrac {A \land B \ \ [A], [B] \vdash C}{C}$

---

*Note* from this point of view, the $\top$ rules are not very useful: they amounts to specifying the trivial fact that adding or removing $\top$ from the set of premises does not affect the validity of the inference.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to get a hand on a copy of *Structural Proof Theory*. Hopefully, then your comments will get clearer. In particular, I hope I will then be able to explain why there is apparently a "bijective correspondence between these 'rules‘“.  In *Proofs and Types* Girard emphasizes that two (syntactically) different SC derivations can give the same ND derivation.

Comment: @M.C. - Just a fruther comment to what Mauro correctly said. One thing is sequent calculus (SC, which can handle only sequents, and it characterized by left and right rules), another thing is natural deduction (ND, which is characterized by introduction rules and elimination rules). It turns out that ND can be presented in many different styles: Fitch-style, tree-like style with formulas, tree-like style with sequents, etc.; the different preentations of ND are isomorphic, in the sense that a ND derivation in one style or another are exactly the same object, just a different graphical look.

Comment: @M.C. - _Proof and Types_ shows the relation between SC and the tree-like style presentation with _formulas_ of ND. Note that the translation is not an isomorphism, in the sense that two different derivations in SC can be translated in the same derivation in ND. To have an intuition about the fact that the tree-like presentation of ND with formulas is isomorphic to the tree-like presentation of ND with sequents, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3774598/288417).

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: Thank you, the link you gave was helpful. I still do not see, however, why one should read the tree-like style with sequents of ND bottom-up?

Comment: @M.C. - The way [Blute et al.](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/nets/nets.pdf) talk of "natural deduction" is a bit unusual. Natural deduction (ND) is any proof system that acts on formulas, introducing and eliminating connectives in the conclusion of each inference rule. The way their rules match this "ND pattern" is uncommon, not obvious and somehow dual to what I explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3774598/288417). I can give you more insights in a answer to a separated post. Anyway, I wouldn't say that one should read the tree-like style with sequents of ND bottom-up.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: Thank you! I think I understand Blute's usage of the term "natural deduction" better now than a few days ago. If new questions come up, I will post a seperated question.