# Proof of distributivity of $\land$ over $\lor$ using disjE in natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs, automated-theorem-proving

I'm learning about natural deduction from https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ar//slides02.pdf

I'm trying to understand its proof of

$$
P \land (Q \lor R) \vDash (P \land Q) \lor (P \wedge R)
$$

which is given as

$$
\frac{
    \displaystyle
    \frac{
      P \land (Q \lor R)
    }{
      Q \lor R
     }
    \quad
    \frac{
      \displaystyle
      \frac{
        \displaystyle
        \frac{P \land (Q \lor R)}{P}
        \quad[Q]
      }{
        (P \land Q)
      }
    }{
      (P \land Q) \lor (P \wedge R)
    }
    \quad
    \frac{
      \displaystyle
      \frac{
        \displaystyle
        \frac{P \land (Q \lor R)}{P}
        \quad[R]
      }{
        (P \land R)
      }
    }{
      (P \land Q) \lor (P \wedge R)
    }
}
{
  (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)
}
$$
I think I understand the application of the various rules: conjI, conjunct1, conjunct2, disjI1, disjI2. But I'm having trouble reasoning about how disjE is applied on the bottom step. The structure of the proof doesn't seem to match how the rule is given:

$$
\frac{P \lor Q\quad \begin{matrix}[P] \\ \vdots \\ R\end{matrix} \quad \begin{matrix}[Q] \\ \vdots \\ R\end{matrix}}{R}
$$

Specifically, for each of the $[P]$ and $[Q]$ terms in the rule (so $[Q]$ and $[R]$ in the proof) there is an extra premise(?) next to it, so it's not clear to me that disjE can be applied.

How disjE is applied here?

Comment: Why do you think that the last rule in the given derivation does not match with the general scheme of the rule for elimination of disjunction?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I've added a bit of detail on why I don't think it's clear that it can be applied

Comment: The additional premises don't affect the applicability, it's still an instance of the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last rule in the given derivation in the OP *does* match with the general scheme of the rule for elimination of disjunction $\lor_E$ below (I only changed the letters with respect to the rule in the OP)

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\frac{Q \lor R \quad \begin{matrix}[Q] \\ \vdots \\ P\end{matrix} \quad \begin{matrix}[R] \\ \vdots \\ P\end{matrix}}{P}\lor_E
\end{equation}

Indeed, in $(1)$, writing

$$\tag{2}
\begin{matrix}[Q] \\ \vdots \\ P\end{matrix}
$$

means that there is a derivation whose conclusion is $P$ and that a number (possibly 0) of occurrences of $Q$ *among* the assumptions for that derivation will be discharged by the rule $\lor_E$ in $(1)$. It does not exclude the possibility that in $(2)$ there are *other* assumptions (or other occurrences of the same assumption $Q$ that won't be discharged later by $\lor_E$). Said differently, $(2)$ does not mean that $Q$ is the only "legitimate" assumption that can be used to derive $P$.

In the given derivation in the OP, the subderivation below

$$\tag{3}
\displaystyle
    \frac{
      \displaystyle
      \frac{
        \displaystyle
        \frac{P \land (Q \lor R)}{P}
        \quad[Q]
      }{
        (P \land Q)
      }
    }{
      (P \land Q) \lor (P \wedge R)
    }
$$
perfectly matches the pattern in $(2)$. Indeed, $(3)$ is a derivation where there are two assumptions:

- $Q$, which will be discharged later by the rule $\lor_E$,
- $P \land (Q \lor R)$, which is a "legitimate" hypothesis according to the text of the exercise.

Comment: I've been wrestling with this: 'Said differently, (2) does not mean that Q is the only "legitimate" assumption that can be used to derive A'. I feel like it should be more explicit in the notation somehow - why isn't it? Can the other rules be applied even if there are more assumptions in the derivation?

Comment: @MichalCharemza - Essentially, this implicit notation is used to be synthetic and not heavy. The principle is that in the general scheme of a rule, the only assumptions that are represented are the ones that will "change their status", that is, that will be discarded. Note the difference between the premise of a rule (that are always explicit in the general scheme of a rule) and the hypotheses of a derivation (that are implicit in the general scheme of a rule, except for the ones that are discharged).

Comment: @MichalCharemza - Note also that, in propositional logic, the only rules discharging hypotheses are the introduction of implication and the elimination of disjunction. The other rules do not require to represent any hypotheses of the derivation, because the application of those rules do not change the hypotheses of a derivation.

Comment: @MichalCharemza - By the way, there are presentations of natural deduction where the hypotheses of a derivation are made explicit in every rule, for instance the presentation of natural deduction based on sequents. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3774598/288417) for a quick discussion, or open a new post if you want to know more about it.

Comment: Thanks! I am starting to get it. "there are presentations of natural deduction where the hypotheses of a derivation are made explicit in every rule" is especially helpful. Even just glancing at the expressions in the linked answer, without fully understanding, I can see they have a "context".