# Can I interpret $\models$ as $\implies$ while proving logical expressions using different techniques?

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus, artificial-intelligence

In the book by Artificial Intelligence by Norvig and Russel, I came across following problem:

> Prove if correct: $(A ∧ B) \models (A ⇔ B).$

I quickly interpreted $\models$ as $\implies$ and tried to prove it using the [truth table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+and+B%29+implies+%28A+xnor+B%29):

[image]

It seems that at least while interpreting $\models$ as $\implies$, the statement is true. Then I gave second thought and did some more reading to come across [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72360/how-is-implication-same-as-entailment) thread. Now I know that the two are not same. But, it turns out, when we don't interpret $\models$ as $\implies$, the statement is still true (my course TA uploaded answers without proof).

So I am wondering:

**Q1.** How exactly the given statement is correct (given that $\models$ and $\implies$ are not same)?
**Q2.** Is my method to interpret both same and then forming truth table, a correct method for such  problems? If not then how I should solve it?
**Q3.** If answer to Q2 is no, then will above method of interpreting $\models$ as $\implies$ and forming truth table always given correct answer? If not, when it will fail to give correct answer?
**Q4.** I also tried to solve the same using [resolution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-825-techniques-in-artificial-intelligence-sma-5504-fall-2002/lecture-notes/Lecture7FinalPart1.pdf):

$$\neg (A\Longleftrightarrow B)\equiv \neg((A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge\neg B))\equiv\neg(A\wedge B)\wedge \neg(\neg A\wedge \neg B)\equiv (\neg A\vee\neg B)\wedge (A \vee B)$$
So my clauses will be:

- $A$ (from $A\wedge B$)
- $B$ (from $A\wedge B$)
- $(\neg A\vee\neg B)$ from $(\neg A\vee\neg B)\wedge (A \vee B)$
- $(A \vee B)$ from $(\neg A\vee\neg B)\wedge (A \vee B)$

[image]

So I was able to derive empty clause, so my assumption $\neg (A\Longleftrightarrow B)$ was incorrect. So $(A ∧ B) \implies (A ⇔ B)$. Will application of resolution technique for $\models$ be exactly same?

**Update**

[This is my updated understanding based on Graham's answer]

**(a)** After reading Graham's answer, I felt that the truth table above is proving the "tautology" $(A ∧ B) \implies (A ⇔ B)$, but not $(A ∧ B) \models (A ⇔ B)$.

**(b)** To prove $(A ∧ B) \models (A ⇔ B)$, I need another truth table, something like this:
[image]

**(c)** Also, I guess the resolution technique is used to prove tautology $(A ∧ B) \implies (A ⇔ B)$ and not $(A ∧ B) \models (A ⇔ B)$. However, I feel we can use the (first) truth table and resolution proving $\implies$ to also prove $\models$, because of the following fact:

> $\varphi\vDash \psi$ iff $M(\varphi)\subseteq M(\psi)$: that is, iff every truth assignment that makes $\varphi$ true also make $\psi$ true. This is the case iff $\vDash \varphi\Rightarrow\psi$, i.e., if the formula $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$ is true in all truth assignments (is a tautology). - [source](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/72363/17040)

Can someone please confirm if my understanding in the above points is correct?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal A \vDash \varphi$ says: "statement $\varphi$ is a semantic consequence of the list of statements $\mathcal A$ (often called the *premises*, or *assumptions*)" and a semantic consequence must be true when all the premises are interpreted as true.  [Note: this list may be of zero, one, or several statements.]

In *propositional logic*, you can use a truth table to establish such a semantic consequence: and $(A\land B)\vDash(A\leftrightarrow B)$ since indeed **"every assignment that values $A\land B$ as true will also value $A\leftrightarrow B$ as true,"** will be shown by a table of every assignment of $A,B$ and the corresponding evaluations of the statements.

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c4|c}A&B & A\land B& A\leftrightarrow B\\\hline\top&\top &\top &\top&\star\\\top&\bot&\bot &\bot\\\bot&\top&\bot&\bot\\\bot&\bot&\bot&\top\\\end{array}}\\\text{the consequent is true in the only row where the premise is true}$$

[Note: the trend this century is to use single bar arrows, $\to,\leftrightarrow$, for logical connectives, and double edge for metalogic inferences, though not all authors do so.]

---

$(A\land B)\to(A\leftrightarrow B)$ is a statement, and moreover one which is a tautology.   That means that it is a logical consequence of no premises at all.  Thus:$$\vDash (A\land B)\to(A\leftrightarrow B)$$

This can also be demonstrated by a truth table, where we show that **"every assignment of $A,B$ will value the whole statement as true."**

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c4|c}A&B & (A\land B)\to(A\leftrightarrow B)\\\hline\top&\top &\top\\\top&\bot&\top\\\bot&\top&\top\\\bot&\bot&\top\\\end{array}}\\\text{the consequent is true in every row}$$

That is not *exactly* the same test, but it is clearly the case that where one works the other will too.

---

It should be noted, truth tables work as semantic proofs only in *classic propositional logic*.  They are less applicable in higher order logics, modal logics, among others.

Comment: Hi, I have understood some points after reading your answer. I have added this understanding at the end of the original question as an update. Can you please confirm if this understanding is correct?

Comment: No, truth tables can prove semantic entailment for other than tautologies, in propositional logic. Semantic entailment is proven when you demonstrate that *"Every model where the premises are valued true will also value the consequent as true."*  Truth tables do this by listing every possible valuation of the literals, and corresponding valuation of the propositions. $\quad$ PS: Resolution also proves this by establishing that *a contradiction occurs when valuing the premises as true and the consequent as false.*

Comment: They are just different tables: with different premises and consequent.

Comment: However, the resolution process for both semantics *does* have the same *conjunctive normal form* for the premise-and-negated-consequent list.

Answer (score 1):

> **(a)** After reading Graham's answer, I felt that the truth table above is proving the "tautology" $(A ∧ B) \implies (A ⇔ B)$, but not $(A ∧ B) \models (A ⇔ B)$.
> **(b)** To prove $(A ∧ B) \models (A ⇔ B)$, I need another truth table, something like this:
> [image]

To be absolutely clear: the difference is this (here, $\psi$ and $\theta$ are **compound propositional formulae**):

1. using a truth table to verify that $(\psi\to \theta)$ is a tautology: construct the truth table of $(\psi\to \theta),$ then verify that the column with the main connective is filled *only* with `1`'s;
2. using a truth table to verify that $(\psi\models \theta):$ construct a truth table containing both $\psi$ and $\theta,$ then verify that in *every* row where $\psi$ has value `1`, $\theta$ also has value `1`.

(1) and (2) are equivalent (the Deduction Theorem and [its converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3773733/21813) formally justifies this).