# How to prove this theorem $(v\lor s)\land(v\rightarrow p)\land(s\rightarrow a)\land\lnot a\vdash p$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I'm noob to Discrete Math, but I need to prove this $(v\lor s)\land(v\rightarrow p)\land(s\rightarrow a)\land\lnot a\vdash p$

If you can explain what shall I do to prove it.

I can create truth table for left part of formula $(v\lor s)\land(v\rightarrow p)\land(s\rightarrow a)\land\lnot a$, but

I don't completely understand what shall I do with right part of formula I mean $\vdash p$

Please explain what I need  to prove: maybe equivalence or tautology or something other or maybe I need to compare left side of formula $(v\lor s)\land(v\rightarrow p)\land(s\rightarrow a)\land\lnot a$ and right side $\vdash p$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I've never seen the notation $\vdash p$, is that the same as $\rightarrow p$?

Comment: $\Gamma \vdash p$ in the context of proof theory means that there exists a proof of $p$ from the set of assumptions $\Gamma$, where a proof is meant in the syntactic way, loosely: a sequence of valid rules of deduction.

Comment: Which proof system are you allowed to use?

Comment: Related: [Can I interpret ⊨
 as ⟹
 while proving logical expressions using different techniques?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4647695/21813)

Comment: How are you supposed to demonstrate/proof this?  You mention a truth-table .. can you use a truth-table to prove this?  Then again, the $\vdash$ symbol is typically used for a syntactical derivation, i.e. something more like a formal proof .. is that what you are supposed to do?  So please add to your post *how* you are supposed to demonstrate this.

Comment: I don't know how to demonstrate proof, because I don't understand this task from my teacher at the University, and he told that he will not give any comments.  That's I'm here and and I'm trying to sort out. Thank you so much for any help. And thank you for guidance regarding "syntactical derivation", I will search additional information to understand how to solve this problem. MANY THANKS to all of you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose

$$(v\lor s)\land(v\rightarrow p)\land(s\rightarrow a)\land\lnot a.\tag{1}$$

Then from $(1)$,

$$\begin{align}
v\lor s,\tag{2}\\
 v\rightarrow p,\tag{3}\\
 s\rightarrow a,\tag{4}\\
 \lnot a\tag{5}
\end{align}$$

From $(4)$, we have $\lnot s$ or $a$. The latter contradicts $(5)$, so suppose the former. Now $(2)$ gives $v$ or $s$, but $\lnot s$ holds from before, so we have $v$. But now $v$ implies $p$ from $(3)$.

Hence

$$\vdash((v\lor s)\land(v\rightarrow p)\land(s\rightarrow a)\land\lnot a)\to p,$$

but this holds if and only if

$$(v\lor s)\land(v\rightarrow p)\land(s\rightarrow a)\land\lnot a\vdash p.\,\square $$

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I'll be trying to sort all of this. I don't know how to like you or say BIG THANK YOU to increase your status.

Comment: You're welcome, @NadineSk. I'm glad I could help.